# Total width of element (including padding and border) in jQuery

Tags: jquery, dimensions

As in the subject, how can one get the total width of an element, including its border and padding, using jQuery?  I've got the jQuery dimensions plugin, and running `.width()` on my `760px-wide`, `10px padding` DIV returns `760`.

Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, but if my element manifests itself as `780 pixels wide` and Firebug tells me that there's `10px padding` on it, but calling `.width()` only gives 760, I'd be hard pressed to see how.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

**[Update]**

The original answer was written prior to jQuery 1.3, and the functions that existed at the time where not adequate by themselves to calculate the whole width.

Now, as [J-P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349705/total-width-of-element-including-padding-and-border-in-jquery/673622#673622) correctly states, jQuery has the functions [outerWidth](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/outerWidth) and [outerHeight](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/outerHeight) which include the `border` and `padding` by default, and also the `margin` if the first argument of the function is `true`

---

**[Original answer]**

The `width` method no longer requires the `dimensions` plugin, because it has been added to the `jQuery Core`

What you need to do is get the padding, margin and border width-values of that particular div and add them to the result of the `width` method

Something like this:

```
var theDiv = $("#theDiv");
var totalWidth = theDiv.width();
totalWidth += parseInt(theDiv.css("padding-left"), 10) + parseInt(theDiv.css("padding-right"), 10); //Total Padding Width
totalWidth += parseInt(theDiv.css("margin-left"), 10) + parseInt(theDiv.css("margin-right"), 10); //Total Margin Width
totalWidth += parseInt(theDiv.css("borderLeftWidth"), 10) + parseInt(theDiv.css("borderRightWidth"), 10); //Total Border Width
```

*Split into multiple lines to make it more readable*

That way you will always get the correct computed value, even if you change the padding or margin values from the css

Comment: In general, I would rather believe jQuery than doing the calculation on my own. The problem is that the width() function does not actually specify what it does in case of "box-sizing: border-box". I just tested it, and it returns the inner width excluding padding etc. This may or may not be correct; different people may expect different things. So the code sample above actually works, but it may not be the most reliable way. As indicated in some other answers, I would recommend using the outerWidth() function instead. It at least promises what it is supposed to in documentation.

Comment: The outerWidth/outerHeight function did not exist when I wrote this answer.

Comment: Just a quick comment on my old code, if anyone's still using it; the `parseInt`s can be changed to the `+` operator to make the code more succinct.  So, `parseInt(theDiv.css("padding-left"), 10)` could be turned to `+theDiv.css("padding-left")` etc...

Answer (score 194):

Anyone else stumbling upon this answer should note that jQuery now (>=1.3) has **`outerHeight`**/**`outerWidth`** functions to retrieve the width including padding/borders, e.g.

```
$(elem).outerWidth(); // Returns the width + padding + borders
```

To include the margin as well, simply pass **`true`**:

```
$(elem).outerWidth( true ); // Returns the width + padding + borders + margins
```

Comment: I don't have edit capability, but I would change the first comment to:

// Returns the width + padding + borders

And change the second comment to 

// Returns the width + padding + borders + margins

Answer (score 2):

looks like outerWidth is broken in the latest version of jquery.

The discrepancy happens when

the outer div is floated,
the inner div has the width set (smaller than the outer div)
the inner div has style="margin:auto"

Answer (score 2):

Just for simplicity I encapsulated Andreas Grech's great answer above in some functions. For those who want a bit of cut-and-paste happiness.

```
function getTotalWidthOfObject(object) {

    if(object == null || object.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    var value       = object.width();
    value           += parseInt(object.css("padding-left"), 10) + parseInt(object.css("padding-right"), 10); //Total Padding Width
    value           += parseInt(object.css("margin-left"), 10) + parseInt(object.css("margin-right"), 10); //Total Margin Width
    value           += parseInt(object.css("borderLeftWidth"), 10) + parseInt(object.css("borderRightWidth"), 10); //Total Border Width
    return value;
}

function  getTotalHeightOfObject(object) {

    if(object == null || object.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    var value       = object.height();
    value           += parseInt(object.css("padding-top"), 10) + parseInt(object.css("padding-bottom"), 10); //Total Padding Width
    value           += parseInt(object.css("margin-top"), 10) + parseInt(object.css("margin-bottom"), 10); //Total Margin Width
    value           += parseInt(object.css("borderTopWidth"), 10) + parseInt(object.css("borderBottomWidth"), 10); //Total Border Width
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

same browsers may return string for border width, in this parseInt will return NaN
so make sure you parse value to int properly.

```
        var getInt = function (string) {
            if (typeof string == "undefined" || string == "")
                return 0;
            var tempInt = parseInt(string);

            if (!(tempInt <= 0 || tempInt > 0))
                return 0;
            return tempInt;
        }

        var liWidth = $(this).width();
        liWidth += getInt($(this).css("padding-left"));
        liWidth += getInt($(this).css("padding-right"));
        liWidth += getInt($(this).css("border-left-width"));
        liWidth += getInt($(this).css("border-right-width"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
$("div.width").append($("div.width").width()+" px");
$("div.innerWidth").append($("div.innerWidth").innerWidth()+" px");   
$("div.outerWidth").append($("div.outerWidth").outerWidth()+" px");         
});


<div class="width">Width of this div container without including padding is: </div>  
<div class="innerWidth">width of this div container including padding is: </div> 
<div class="outerWidth">width of this div container including padding and margin is:     </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.