# Checking element width with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with a website that someone did, and I'm having some difficulties with javascript.

I'm trying to get the current width of a div, and not what's in CSS. When I resize my window, I need to get the new div width (resize by jQuery).

I'm using this code:

```
if(document.getElementById("header").offsetWidth<1270){
    alert("Cheguei aqui");
}
```

I thought that if element width is lower than 1270, I would send an alert. But it isn't working.

This is the header div.

```
    <div id="header">
            <div class="container">
      <div class="two columns" id="logo-wrap"> <a href="index.html">
        <div id="logo2"></div>
        </a>
         <select id="header-mobile-menu">
          <option value="index.html">Home</option>
          <option value="Quem Somos.html">Quem Somos</option>
          <option value="Consulta.html">Consultas</option>
          <option value="Exame.html">Exames</option>
          <option value="Terapias.html">Terapias Alternativas</option>
          <option value="AcaoSocial.html">Ação Social</option>
          <option value="Contato.html">Contato </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="fourteen columns">
        <nav>
          <ul id="menu-header-menu" class="menu">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Quem Somos.html">Quem Somos</a></li>
            <li><a href="Consulta.html">Consultas</a></li>
            <li><a href="Exame.html">Exames</a></li>
            <li><a href="Parceiros.html">Parceiros</a></li>
            <li><a href="Contato.html">Contato</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>  
      </div>
<!-- Place this tag where you want the search box to render -->
<div class="searchgoogle"><gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only></div>

      <br class="clear" />
    </div>
<div id="socialdiv">
    <div id="social-button"> 
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/centralife" target="_blank">
            <div id="facebook-img"></div></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/CentralLife1" target="_blank">
            <div id="twitter-img"></div></a>    
        <a href="http://www.orkut.com.br/Main#Profile?uid=9858410708954250541" target="_blank">
            <div id="orkut-img"></div></a>    
            <a href="http://centralifesaude.blogspot.com.br/" target="_blank">
            <div id="blog-img"></div></a>
            <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Uhjl-ykpt8&feature=plcp" target="_blank">
            <div id="youtube-img"></div></a>
           </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS have a lot of "header" declarations, it's to hard to get'em. By the way, this javascript doesn't affect my CSS, does it?

What's wrong?

Comment: Could we see the HTML and CSS please? Maybe a jsfiddle?

Comment: have you got an id="header" in your html?

Comment: Values that are lower than 1270px crash my layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know but my code is working well:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   if($('#header').width() < 1270){
       alert('teste');
   }
})
```

Comment: well, I said i was new in Javascript. Forget about event handler. Put $(window).resize(function(){ and it worked. Thanks, or Valeu hahaha

Comment: So, this only work if I resize my windows. And if I started it with small size? Like a smarthphone? How can I check my window at start?

Comment: $(function() {
    //Check function here
});

Answer (score 1):

Since you're apparently using jQuery:

```
$("#header").width()
```

will return the width of the header element

Answer (score -1):

see that topic

[Total width of element (including padding and border) in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349705/total-width-of-element-including-padding-and-border-in-jquery)

there is a explanation to take an element width and others attributes

Answer (score -1):

To get the precise Div width, you can use getBoundingClientRect() and subtract Right from Left.