# $(li).width() returning value which includes padding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width

http://jsfiddle.net/MeoMix/8zg2V/83/

I've got the following jsFiddle. The idea is that when a context menu item which is too long is displayed, it renders with ellipsis, but on mouseover it pans through the text.

The code in question:

```
//Provides helper methods for non-specific functionality.
define('helpers', [], function () {
    'use strict';

    return {
        scrollElementInsideParent: function(element, parent) {
            //  Scroll the element if its too long to read.
            $(element).mouseover(function () {

                var distanceToMove = $(this).width() - $(parent).width();

                console.log("My width and parent width:", $(this).width(), $(parent).width());

                $(this).animate({
                    marginLeft: "-" + distanceToMove + "px"
                }, {
                    //  Just a feel good value; scales as the text gets longer
                    duration: 15 * distanceToMove,
                    easing: 'linear'
                });

            }).mouseout(function () {
                $(this).stop(true).animate({ marginLeft: 0 });
            });
        }
    };
```

Here I log the element being scrolled upon's width as well as its parents width. The console outputs:

> My width and parent width: 360 230

but this seems incorrect when looking at the metrics:

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: Do you have `box-sizing: border-box` on them?

Comment: Trying using `outerWidth()`

Comment: @Terry, he doesn't want the padding to be included.

Comment: @bfavaretto You can see the jsfiddle. There is no box-sizing: border-box on them. Terry outerWidth() returns the same value as .width() and .innerWidth() and .outerWidth(true).

Comment: You're kidding, right? `this` refers to the `<a>` element, which has a width of `auto`, and ends up being the width of `230px`. Why are you looking at the `<li>`?

Comment: @Ian The <a>'s width exceeds the li element. The <a> reports having a width of 360px. I am panning the <a> inside of the <li> element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349705/total-width-of-element-including-padding-and-border-in-jquery

Comment: @SeanAnderson Maybe I'm misunderstanding again. Let me look again

Comment: @Ian you are correct: `$(this).parent().width()` returns 200

Comment: @SeanAnderson You're not an idiot. A simple overlooking. I'd expect `parent` to be a parent of `this` too, but at the same time, why would they bother passing it when you could easily use `$(this).parent()`? Maybe it's defined better in the docs (I'm too lazy too look)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code, the `parent` parameter refers to the `<ul>`. Use `$(this).parent()` to get the `<li>`

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/EsL2X/

Comment: Thanks. Right under my nose. I appreciate it. :)

Comment: @SeanAnderson No problem at all, just think of debugging that kind of stuff next time :) I'm just glad you got an answer that fixes it!

Comment: Oh yeah.. I was just working on this late last night and thought I had explored all my options. I was in the wrong mindset for finding that this morning, apparently. Cheers.

Comment: @SeanAnderson Hey, that's what this place is for :)