# triple caption over image are work bad

Tags: css, caption

I have some problem. I tried to position the title over the image

- first title (cat1) can be small or long
- second title (cat 2) juste after the first title
- third title (after the 2nd title to right)
  these title must be on inline

see my demo jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cyphos/jntea/]

thank you for your response

Comment: If you could add an image of what exactly you want to accomplish, that would be helpful. Don't really understand it currently.

Comment: no, I want say I should put the second title juste after the first title (margin-right : 2px by example) and the third title to right over the image (non on the web page)

Comment: If my answer below isn't what you want, then I still have no idea what you are describing. Post an image of what you want it to look like instead.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, how you accomplish this depends on what you are OK with creating. If you can specify the width of each element, then it isn't a problem to accomplish. You could then simply specify widths for both the left and right elements, then position the center one directly in between. See this fiddle as an example:

[CSS only Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KY8Jh/)

This uses the box-sizing border-box model to simplify things. [Read this for clarification](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

basically:

```
.cta1 {left:0;width:150px;}
.cta2 {left:150px;right:150px;}
.cta3 {right:0;width:150px;}
```

OR

if you want these items to be dynamic, you will need to use Javascript/jQuery to get the width of the elements and then set the `left` and `right` properties of the center one accordingly. An example in jQuery

[jQuery based fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eKebJ/2/)

```
var cat1Width = $('.cat1').width();
cat1Width = cat1Width + 26; //26 being a pixel measure of the padding of the element
$('.cat2').css('left', cat1Width);
```

With this, you will have to then add the padding values to the cta1Width variable, as jQuery does not return a width value that includes the padding. Either do this manually (by adding the pixel value yourself), or you can also extract the padding width with the jQuery [see this thread for info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349705/total-width-of-element-including-padding-and-border-in-jquery)